# Why does Fixed Menu look different on inner page, then main page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site which I have modified to use a fixed menu bar at the top.  On the home page, it looks fine. But on the inner pages, which uses the same header, the top padding changes and the menu no longer looks correctly.

I can change the top padding for the inner page so it looks correct, but then the home page no longer looks correct.

I have used F12 dev tools to try to determine what the issue is, but it eludes me.  You can see the site at [Test Site](http://js1.biz).  Just click on the blog page/ then back to the home page, and you will see the difference.

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can not tell you, why it works on your homepage, but not blog, you are missing a sort of important css propery, which takes care of such things, **#top-area** add `top:0;`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, looks much better now.